# How can I add an overlay label on table of dynamic images?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to add an overlay labels on a table of images, these images are randomly shuffled every time, but there will be always location number on top of each image corners.
How can I add that using HTML?
get a look at a sample:

[image: Display image inline]

Here is my table code, what should I add to add labels on my images?

```
<table id="userArrayTable" >
<tr id="trHeader">
<td id="td">1</td> <td id="td">2</td> <td id="td">3</td> <td id="td">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/foodicons/food-1.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/foodicons/food-2.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/foodicons/food-3.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/foodicons/food-4.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> 
</tr>

<tr id="tr2">
<td><img src="images/fruitsicons/fruites-1.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/fruitsicons/fruites-2.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/fruitsicons/fruites-3.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/fruitsicons/fruites-4.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td>  
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img src="images/animalsicons/animal-1.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/animalsicons/animal-2.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/animalsicons/animal-3.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/animalsicons/animal-4.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td>   
</tr>

<tr id="tr4">
<td><img src="images/jobsicons/job-1.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/jobsicons/job-2.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/jobsicons/job-3.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> <td><img src="images/jobsicons/job-4.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></td> 
</tr>

</table>



@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 0 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;

}   
.form .message a {
  color: #DBEFDC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #cccccc, #cccccc);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}

#userArrayTable td {
padding:0px 8px;
height:10px;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}

#trHeader
{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
color:#000;
font-size:40px;
}
```

Comment: Are the labels moving with the images?

Comment: Are you stuck on some code, or are you asking us to write something from scratch?

Comment: Thanks all, the labels are not moving at all. I need to guide me where  I can find a useful piece of html code to be inserted in my html table, that will provide me the ability to add a permanent label on whatever the image was in this field. just like the letters on the given sample.

Comment: you can use any tag  ::: p - span- div- :after:before -::: then you just need to adjust the CSS; anyway we need to see your html&css

Comment: @DaniP I have added the table code, is that enough? or should I add all HTML code of the page?

Comment: a little question you will change the enitre table or just the src of the imgs ?

Comment: Css now are available also, I hope someone help me with the right code that I should use.

Comment: I don't need to change the table or images sources, all that I need is a code that will add an overlay label or image in a corner on my images. just take another look at the given sample. You will find that letters "circles labels" have been added on the images in spite of that they are related to the field of the table, not to the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `span` element after each `img` and style it to be on the top of the img like this:

```css
#userArrayTable td {
  position:relative;
}
#userArrayTable span {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  z-index:10;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<table id="userArrayTable">
  <tr id="trHeader">
    <td id="td">1</td>
    <td id="td">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
      <span>A</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
      <span>B</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
      <span>Z</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
      <span>X</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great :) I did that without circle now since I am using small symbols not big images.

Comment: @MRAN glad to help U mate